# How to set the alpha of an UIImage in SWIFT programmatically?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimage, uicontrolstate

I found a lot solutions here but not for **Swift**, and I know you can do this with a UIImageView, but in my case i need an programmatically set alpha transparent background image for an **UIButton**. Best would be an UIImage extension!

```
let img = UIImage(named: "imageWithoutAlpha")
var imgInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 24, 0, 24)
image = image!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(imgInsets)

let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: img!.size.width, height: img!.size.height))
myButton.setBackgroundImage(img, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
myButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20)
myButton.setTitle("Startbutton", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
myButton.sizeToFit()
view.addSubview(myButton)
```

Current result:

[image: current]

Desired result:

[image: desired]

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Luckily I was able to help myself and would like to share with you my solution:

**Swift 3**

```
// UIImage+Alpha.swift

extension UIImage {  

    func alpha(_ value:CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        draw(at: CGPoint.zero, blendMode: .normal, alpha: value)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage!   
    }
}
```

The above new Swift extension I added to my project and then I changed the UIButton example as follows, to have an alpha transparent background image with a transparency of 50%.

```
let img = UIImage(named: "imageWithoutAlpha")!.alpha(0.5)
let myButton = UIButton()

myButton.setBackgroundImage(img, for: .normal)
```

Comment: In swift 2 I had to replace kCGBlendModeMultiply with CGBlendMode.Multiply, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309521/error-use-of-unresolved-identifier-kcgblendmodemultiply

Comment: can you post an swift 3 version?

Comment: swift 3 version added!

Comment: This seems to ignore color. I have an image with colors in it and when I apply this method, the resulting image is gray (but it does have the appropriate alpha).

Comment: In reading some of https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101 it seems like .normal should work fine. Anyone else experiencing this "gray-scale" effect?

Answer (score 35):

The easiest way is to put your `UIImage` inside a `UIImageView` and set the alpha there.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "imageWithoutAlpha")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.alpha = 0.5

myButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: sorry, but that makes no sense!

Comment: What exactly doesn't make sense?

Comment: I tried your solution, but the transparency/opacity of the background image will not change

Comment: Well, try again because it works 100%. Test properly before downvoting answers.

Comment: Answer to another question. Question is not "how to change opacity of UIImageView".

Question is "how to change alpha of UIImage"

Comment: You are creating `imageView` but then never using it. You can't set UIView via `UIButton.setBackgroundImage`.

Comment: I have to agree with gondo here.

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 5, iOS 10+**

If your app doesn't support operating systems prior to iOS 10 then you can take advantage of the more robust `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` UIKit drawing API.

```
extension UIImage {
    func withAlpha(_ a: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: imageRendererFormat).image { (_) in
            draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size), blendMode: .normal, alpha: a)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let img = UIImage(named: "someImage")?.withAlpha(0.5)
```

Answer (score 9):

I was able to set the alpha using the following code:

```
self.imageView.image = UIImageView(image: "image.png")
imageView.alpha = 0.5
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted: it proved an easy fix for me.

Comment: Answer to another question. Question is not "how to change opacity of UIImageView". Question is "how to change alpha of UIImage"