# Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'kCGBlendModeMultiply'

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7, xcode7-beta2

I recently updated to Xcode 7, beta 3.

And I've run into some issues, I can't seem to find any questions for on SO.

When I run my application, i get 3 errors:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'kCGBlendModeMultiply'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'kCGLineCapRound'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'kCGLineJoinMiter'

However the 2 latter ones, disappear, although I assume they will show up after the first one is fixed (hence why I included it in this question).

I didn't see anything in the release notes about these being removed? So I'm a bit stuck at what to do. I tried rewriting the lines of course, but the 3 things I used don't show up as options anymore. In case that they are just gone in the latest Swift 2.0, what can I use instead?

Here's the code for the first error.

```
    func alpha(value:CGFloat)->UIImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 0.0)
    
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let area = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
    
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply)
    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, value)
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, self.CGImage)
    
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    return newImage;
}
```

Here's the code for the 2 latter errors:

```
for layer in [ self.top, self.middle, self.bottom ] {
        layer.fillColor = nil
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        layer.lineWidth = 4
        layer.miterLimit = 4
        layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        let strokingPath = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(layer.path, nil, 4, kCGLineCapRound, kCGLineJoinMiter, 4)
        
        layer.bounds = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(strokingPath)
        
        layer.actions = [
            "strokeStart": NSNull(),
            "strokeEnd": NSNull(),
            "transform": NSNull()
        ]
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work:

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, CGBlendMode.Multiply)
```

... or even just this:

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, .Multiply)
```

If you `Ctrl-click` on `CGContextSetBlendMode` and then from its declaration jump (in the same way) to declaration of `CGBlendMode` then you will see:

```
enum CGBlendMode : Int32 {

    /* Available in Mac OS X 10.4 & later. */
    case Normal
    case Multiply
    case Screen
    case Overlay

    // ...
}
```

Similarly, the other line that produces the error should be changed to:

```
let strokingPath = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(layer.path, nil, 4, .Round, .Miter, 4)
```