# Ambiguous use of 'kGMSMarkerAnimationPop' Error in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, ios9

Im having an error while trying to animate a GMSMarker, I have followed the Google documentation and various guides but it keeps returning an error, below is my code:

```
func placeMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    if locationMarker != nil {
        locationMarker.map = nil
    }

    locationMarker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
    locationMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(purple)
    locationMarker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    locationMarker.snippet = "The best place on earth."
    locationMarker.map = mapView
}
```

Which returns the error Ambiguous use of 'kGMSMarkerAnimationPop'

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: Please check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309521/error-use-of-unresolved-identifier-kcgblendmodemultiply/, maybe it will give you some clues.

Answer (score 6):

upgrading google map pod won't work, at least until 1.12.3.

1. change GMSMarkerAnimation in GMSMarker.h from this:

   ```
   typedef enum {
     /** No animation (default). */
     kGMSMarkerAnimationNone = 0,

     /** The marker will pop from its groundAnchor when added. */
     kGMSMarkerAnimationPop,
   } GMSMarkerAnimation;
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GMSMarkerAnimation){
     /** No animation (default). */
     kGMSMarkerAnimationNone = 0,

     /** The marker will pop from its groundAnchor when added. */
     kGMSMarkerAnimationPop,
   } ;
   ```
2. change

   `locationMarker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop`

   to

   `locationMarker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.Pop`

Comment: just add: `locationMarker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
` with lower case(`pop`)!

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3/GoogleMaps 2.3.0. The new syntax is :

```
marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
```

Answer (score 3):

For me this happens when I upgrade from GoogleMap `1.10.3` to `1.11.1` using CocoaPod. Previously using 1.10.3 it requires me to import all of the header files of GoogleMap in `Bridging-Header.h` file.

To remove this ambiguous error, I just commented out all the imported headers in `Bridging-Header.h`

Comment: Exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I looked around and I found an answer that worked for me:

```
locationMarker.appearAnimation = GoogleMaps.kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3
marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationpop

Swift 4

marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop