# Swift Error - use of unresolved identifier 'kGMSMarkerAnimationPop'

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, xcode8, gmsmapview

I am getting this error

> use of unresolved identifier 'kGMSMarkerAnimationPop'

when I use the following code in Swift 3:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 14)
mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
mapView?.settings.myLocationButton = true
view = mapView
let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
marker.title = "Sydney"
marker.snippet = "Australia"
marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop // the error is occurring in this line
marker.map = mapView
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: try kGMSMarkerAnimation.Pop

Comment: @Anbu  when I tried that I am getting error as use of unresolved identifier 'kGMSMarkerAnimation'

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656475/ambiguous-use-of-kgmsmarkeranimationpop-error-in-swift-2/35439813

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous use of 'kGMSMarkerAnimationPop' Error in Swift 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656475/ambiguous-use-of-kgmsmarkeranimationpop-error-in-swift-2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Swift 3/4 and GoogleMaps 2.3.0. 
The new syntax is :

```
marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
```

[Ambiguous use of 'kGMSMarkerAnimationPop' Error in Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656475/ambiguous-use-of-kgmsmarkeranimationpop-error-in-swift-2/35439813)

Answer (score 0):

try 
`marker.appearAnimation = .pop`