# changing the alpha image backround of a button swift

Tags: swift, button

I need to set the alpha of the image background  of a button when pressed , I've searched online on the code for that but I haven't found something , How can I do it ? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change button background color using swift language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427284/change-button-background-color-using-swift-language)

Comment: I posted the wrong question for duplicate,  should have been http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517866/how-to-set-the-alpha-of-a-uiimage-in-swift-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can try for change button image or their alpha as per your requirement.