# Create a gradient overlay over an image

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

How do you create a gradient overlay to get this kind of effect?

https://dribbble.com/shots/2199202-Today-s-Tasks

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you running into problems? (I assume you've done a search and tried out some of the many, many, many examples out there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like it is a pink to orange gradient with an opacity of about 60%

What I would do is create it on a design software like Sketch (which I use and love). It is super easy to create a gradient on there and there are tons of tutorials. You can get a 30-day trial for free ;). After making the gradient, you can just plop it into your assets folder and add a UIImageView to your project to get that gradient in your app.

If you want to create the gradient programmatically, here is a link to make a gradient: https://www.raywenderlich.com/90693/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-2

...and to change the opacity of a CGRect: [How to set the alpha of an UIImage in SWIFT programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517866/how-to-set-the-alpha-of-an-uiimage-in-swift-programmatically)

Hope this helps! If you like this answer, it would mean so much to just give it a checkmark. Have a great day. Cheers, Theo