# How to change the opacity of the background Image of a UIButton in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift

A quick question, how can I change the opacity (alpha value) of the Background Image of a UIButton? Thanks for the help!

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
    
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "BG"), for: .normal)
    
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517866/how-to-set-the-alpha-of-an-uiimage-in-swift-programmatically#:~:text=normal%2C%20alpha%3A%20value)%20let,with%20a%20transparency%20of%2050%25.  Please check this link, This question has already been answered.

Comment: @Kudos Thanks for sharing the answer:)

Comment: Please upvote my answer. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the alpha of an UIImage in SWIFT programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517866/how-to-set-the-alpha-of-an-uiimage-in-swift-programmatically)